# Javascript: Execute method on object created by callback

Tags: javascript, callback, coffeescript

I'm creating an object inside some asynchronous JS code. When the object is created I want to call a method on it. I'm a bit stumped how I can refer to the new object to call a method on it.

Here's my coffeescript. The code adds markers to a google map:

```
addLocation: (name, id, lat, lng, options, callback) ->
  # Add a new location to the map
  # 
  # @param string name - name to give the location
  # @param int id - ID of the location if stored in the database already
  # @param double lat - latitude
  # @param double lng - longitude
  # @param json options - options to use while adding the location
  console.log("Adding new location '#{name}' (#{lat}, #{lng}) to map") if debug

  @__setVisible true, =>
    location = new Location(this, id, name)
    location.setLatLng(lat, lng, options)
    @locations.add(location)

    callback() if callback

    return location
```

And here's where I invoke this method. I want to call a method on the returned 'location' object, but how can I bind in the callback to an object that hasn't been instantiated yet?

```
__addLocation: (resultLocation) ->
  # Add a new location to the map and centre the view in on it
  name = $(@nameElement).val() 
  lat = resultLocation.geometry.location.lat()
  lng = resultLocation.geometry.location.lng()

  @map.addLocation name, null, lat, lng, { draggable: true }, ->
    # location doesn't exist at this point so the following line fails
    location.setShowInfoWindowOnClick(true)
    @map.centerMap(location)
```

How can I execute location.setShowInfoWindowOnClick(true)?

Comment: That's the oddest looking Javascript I have seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `addLocation` you will want to invoke the callback like;

```
callback location
```

And then in your code;

```
@map.addLocation name, null, lat, lng, { draggable: true }, (location) ->
    location.setShowInfoWindowOnClick true
    @map.centerMap location
```

Comment: I'll modify it for coffeescript if you like

Comment: Thanks @agreco.  Beat me to it.